# Where can I download offline documentation for google cloud datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Is there a better way to download the google cloud datastore docs for offline viewing than to use a web crawler?

I have not found anything yet! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but we don't currently support this for any of the documentation hosted on developers.google.com.