# Offline version of Google Cloud Documentation

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

Can I have a offline version of [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/) . My internet is erratic here. I have the doc that is shipped with SDK but I dont find anything abt google cloud.

Comment: THIS IS ridiculous ... READ the TITLE of that question above, that guy was talking about DATASTORE, not the whole google cloud...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but They don't currently support this for any of the documentation hosted on developers.google.com.
You can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730698/where-can-i-download-offline-documentation-for-google-cloud-datastore).Here it is answered by a google worker .

Comment: thnk u ...I saw that question, I thought he was talking only about datastore ... then there is NO offline doc..   sigh!!